# How do I increase the number of "Recently Used Applications" in the dashboard?

Tags: unity, unity-dash

How can I increase *the number* of Recently used applications that appear in the Dashboard? In Ubuntu 12.04 (or 14.04), default installation, when you press the SUPER KEY the Dashboard opens, and the top most area says "*Recently Used Applications*"...

It only shows **1 row containing 5 icons**, but can I make it show more? for example 2 rows or more? (Yes you can click to expand it, but How can we increase the maximum number of rows)?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version is this? I'm using 12.04 and I have about 23 recent applications there..

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04, and 14.04 both exhibit the behaviour described above. When you press the SUPER KEY the Dashboard opens, and the Recently Used Applications is only 1 row of 4-5 icons. Yes you can click to expand it, but how can we increase it to 2 or 3 rows by default? Hope this makes sense, thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: But once you expand it once, it stays expanded, right?

Comment: Unfortunately, once you reboot it becomes non-expanded again. Good suggestion though, but after I reboot it needs to be expanded again if that makes sense.

Comment: I think the better question here would be how to make the recently used applications expanded automatically on login. Just my thoughts though.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried increasing resolution above 800x600? at 1360x768 I have 8, not 5. Granted this isn't a full screenful, but it's more than you've been getting.

see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSviF.jpg)

The Recently Used items are displayed by GNOME Activity Journal (Privacy). More information on that part of the project is available [here](https://launchpad.net/gnome-activity-journal)

The Zeitgeist Framework powers it. More information on that project is available [here](https://launchpad.net/zeitgeist)

Comment: I couldn't find anything in compiz settings nor dconf that will do what you want. A setting to reduce the Icon size would also have positive results. Hmmm.

Comment: I did, it increases, but still was hoping for a .config file or something that allows you to customize unity for this

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/471074/301745) has a solution for you. It would set the dash to just show apps when you open it.