# Keeping Ubuntu dash just for searching installed applications

Tags: unity, unity-dash

I appreciate the work on Ubuntu Unity dash, but I really don't need all its features.

I want to keep it for only searching applications.

So, I don't want to see *Search Filters* and the bottom categories. See the screen shot.

> [image]

What should I do for removing them and set it to only search installed applications?

Comment: And simply ignoring them is not an option?

Comment: No, because the dash can be faster without these features...

Comment: You could always use something like `gnome-do` or `synapse` instead.

Comment: I am not familiar with changing these settings. I need some clear steps.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear. Those are not settings (that's why I'm not posting an answer, I doubt you can do what you want without modifying the code). [`synapse`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synapse/) and [`gnome-do`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-do/) are tools that let you search for programs easily, like the dash but simpler.

Comment: @terdon I use my computer for work at various clients and at home. I don't want it to remember and *display* every file, picture, video, etc. when I open the dash widget to start an application.

Comment: @RonSmith huh? It doesn't display anything and remembers the same things as the dash.

Comment: @terdon it displays thumbnails of all the files and photos and videos I have opened recently. I just don't want images from one client showing up when I am at another client or pics of my family, etc.

Comment: @RonSmith I don't know which program you are referring to but I've used both gnome-do and synapse for years and have never seen such images.  It probably depends on the options or theme you choose.

Comment: I am using just plain ubuntu 14.04 out of the box. Whatever UI that is, I can't keep up with all the names. When I click the icon at the top of the application bar, it opens a search window just like in the screenshot attached above and it had apps and photos and files and all kinds of crap.  Flint's answer below fixed it for me though.

Answer (score 9):

Without removing unity-lens and packages, you should change scope to only applications by following command in terminal:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Dash scopes "['applications.scope']"
```

In this way **lens are kept** but when you click on dash **only applications are searched**. And you can search in other len if you wish.

Comment: That didn't do anything

Comment: you have to restart Unity

Comment: this still works in 16.04; but yes, reboot (or restarting unity) is required after setting it. (nb: restarting unity will unceremoniously kill all your applications anyway; a reboot takes longer, but is a little less surprising)

Comment: This keeps getting "unset" for some reason. "Files & folders" still periodically show up, and I must select "filter results" and de-select "files & folders".  Repeatedly. Not sure what keeps re-enabling "files & folders" to be included in the search results. _All I want to search for is applications._ But it won't stay that way.

Answer (score 4):

Those little "category icons" at the bottom of dash are called `lens` and they can be individually removed by uninstalling their packages:

> unity-lens-applications
>   unity-lens-files
>   unity-lens-friends
>   unity-lens-music
>   unity-lens-photos
>   unity-lens-video

Comment: +1, That a good point. Also, I still want to remove the GUI elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply work quickly and only show results from your machine, do the following:

```
System Settings > Security & Privacy 
goto search tab
turn off "Include online search results"
```

This effectively limits your search results to applications.

Comment: That will still not stop searching in files. It will just turn off the online search.

Comment: The OP is asking something different here. Your answer does not seem to be specific to the question asked. Could you please stick to the question please. Thanks